# Encoding last audio frame with avcodec_encode_audio2(). *got_packet_ptr == 0

Tags: c, ffmpeg

Looking at `ffmpeg` `examples/muxing.c` . When I encode `mp3`, in 2/3 cases `got_packet` is zero and if it's zero for the last frame, I have no `AVPacket` to write to the file.

How to tell `ffmpeg` to flush the remaining data to a packet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call avcodec_encode_audio2() with null frame

> when flushing an encoder that has the CODEC_CAP_DELAY capability set